# Spring JMS configuration of a queue Consumer

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am trying to run a very basic application to learn Spring JMS + ActiveMQ. I see my Producer creating the message (sysout), but nothing shows up in my Consumer and no exception is thrown. I think I am missing something simple here; would really appreciate any help.

[EDITED, THE FOLLOWING CODE WORKS]

Producer:

```
@Component
public class JmsMessageProducer
{
    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate template;

    public void generateMessages() throws JMSException
    {
        template.send(new MessageCreator()
        {
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException
            {
                System.out.println("sending..");
                TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("this is a Producer created message!");
                return message;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Consumer:

```
@Component
public class JmsMessageConsumer implements MessageListener {
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            TextMessage tm = (TextMessage) message;
            try {
                System.out.println("CONSUMER - received ["+tm.getText()+"]");
            }
            catch (Throwable th) {
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Producer Configuration:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="mrpomario.springcore.jms"/> <!-- finds the JmsMessageProducer -->

<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:8082"/>
</bean>

<bean id="pomarioQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="mrpomario.springcore.jms.queue"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="pomarioQueue"/>
</bean>
```

Consumer Configuration:

```
<jms:listener-container>
    <jms:listener ref="jmsMessageConsumer" method="onMessage" destination="mrpomario.springcore.jms.queue"/>
</jms:listener-container>

<bean id="pomarioQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="mrpomario.springcore.jms.queue"/>
</bean>

<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:8082"/>
</bean>

<amq:broker id="broker" useJmx="false" persistent="false">
    <amq:transportConnectors>
        <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:8082" />
    </amq:transportConnectors>
</amq:broker>
```

Test Case:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:mrpomario/springcore/jms/jms-config.xml")
public class JmsTest
{
    @Autowired
    JmsMessageProducer jmsMessageProducer;

    @Test
    public void test_Single_Queue_Producer_and_Consumer_Unidirectional() throws JMSException
    {
        try
        {
            jmsMessageProducer.generateMessages();
            assertTrue(true);
        }
        catch (Throwable th)
        {
            System.out.println("\n\nJmsTest: remote invocation failed. Ensure the web server is running.\n\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I run the producer inside a Java EE container (mvn jetty:run) where a Spring MVC application also runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are ending up sending to and consuming from two completely different brokers(and subsequently different queues):

Have your broker defined in only one place, say your producer config:

```
<amq:broker id="broker" useJmx="false" persistent="false">
    <amq:transportConnectors>
        <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:8082" />
        <amq:transportConnector uri="vm://localhost" />
    </amq:transportConnectors>
</amq:broker>

<amq:connectionFactory id="jmsFactory" brokerURL="vm://localhost" />
```

From your consumer config remove the broker configuration and have only the connectionFactory:
  Either (if you are in the same VM):

```
<amq:connectionFactory id="jmsFactory" brokerURL="vm://localhost" />
```

Or(If remote):

```
<amq:connectionFactory id="jmsFactory" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:8082" />
```

Comment: Hi Biju, thanks a lot for your feedback! I tried a new configuration layout that follows that of an official Spring tutorial, but still cannot make it work (the consumer is not invoked). Would you please review it and give me feedback?

Comment: Looks good, can you confirm if you are running the producer and the consumer from in the same vm..

Comment: yup, both running in the same VM. The Producer is running using JUnit and the Consumer is running inside an embedded Jetty server (starts with mvn jetty:run). Could this configuration layout be causing me trouble?

Comment: Yes, I think so Pomario, it is likely not the same VM

Comment: hmmm... how would you go about it, I mean, having a Consumer in on VM and the Producer in another?

Comment: If you want consumer in one and producer in another one, that is also straightforward with ActiveMQ, you will have to expose a ActiveMQ as a server - the first broker configuration in my answer does it..`<amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:8082"/>` and connect from the consumer also using the same url instead of `vm://..`

Comment: It works! :-) One last question before I close, @Biju: why do I need to define the Consumer URL twice, one in the connectionFactory bean then duplicate the same URL in the broker bean? See my code (I updated it with the working version)